# UICollectionView reloadData() causes cells to overlap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

### Intro

Every time a user submits a comment, it is uploaded to the database. After that happened, the collectionView is reloaded. However, the **reload does not have the expected behavior**. Instead of adding the one comment to the end of the collectionView, it seems to randomly stack some other comment-cells and only display two comment cells, no matter how many comments there are.

**This is the output of the View Debugger, you can clearly see that the collectionView cells are stacked:**

[image: Image of the stacked collectionViews]

At this point I would like to clarify that this is not a sizing error of the cells. They all have the correct size assigned, and **if I call reloadData** on the collectionView, at a **later point in time**, all the cells are **displayed correctly**.

**I think things will become more clear if you take a look at the gif:**

[image: Gif of the error]

I really don't have any idea where this error comes from or how to fix it.

### Code

**Initialization of collectionView**

```
private lazy var timelineCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 10)
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    cv.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    cv.backgroundColor = .clear
    cv.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.coloredTitleBarHeight - self.getStatusBarHeight(), left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.register(TLContentCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "content-header-cell")
    cv.register(TLContentCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "comment-cell")

    return cv
}()
```

**Code of the UICollectionViewDelegate methods:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "content-header-cell", for: indexPath) as! TLContentCell
    cell.isHeaderCell = true
    cell.timelineContent = tlContentItem
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return commentItems.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "comment-cell", for: indexPath) as! TLContentCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.timelineContent = TLContent(nativeContentItem: commentItems[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: section)
    let headerView = self.collectionView(collectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath) as! TLContentCell


    return headerView.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: UIView.layoutFittingExpandedSize.height),
    withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, // Width is fixed
    verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel) // Height can be as large as needed
}
```

**The code of the comment-upload handler function:**

```
@objc func submitComment() {

    submitCommentButton.isEnabled = false
    submitCommentButton.backgroundColor = ColorCodes.lightGray

    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        print("No user detected. Redirecting to the login screen!")
        self.displayWelcomeScreen()
        return
    }

    guard commentTextView.text.count > 0, let commentContent = commentTextView.text else { print("Submission of comment aborted due to empty content."); return }

    commentTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    commentTextView.text = ""
    calculateTextViewSize()

    ContentUploader.uploadComment(uid: user.uid, content: NativeContentBase(msg: commentContent, usersTagged: [], topicsTagged: [], mediaAssigned: []), referencedContent: tlContentItem.nativeContent.contentId) { (error, comment)  in
        if let err = error {
            print("An error occured during the comment upload: ", err)
            return
        }

        print("Successfully uploaded comment!")
        self.commentItems.append(comment)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(self.commentItems.count)
            self.timelineCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    print("Comment scheduled for submission!")
}
```

I also made sure that I am in the main thread when calling the reloadData() functionality. However, the weird behavior persists.

In order to adjust the collectionView's `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` to the display of the keyboard, **I am using these two functions**:

```
private func adjustScrollBehavior() {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
    let bottomSafeAreaHeight = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0

    // adjust the content Inset of the timelineCollectionView
    let heightOfCommentSection: CGFloat = commentTextViewHeightAnchor.constant + abs(commentTextViewBottomAnchor.constant) + 8 // get the absolute value of the bottomAnchor's constant as it would be negative
    timelineCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: heightOfCommentSection + bottomSafeAreaHeight, right: 0) // does not automatically take care of safe area insets
    timelineCollectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: heightOfCommentSection, right: 0) // automatically takes care of safe area insets
}

func calculateTextViewSize() {
    let minimumSize = commentTextView.layoutMargins.top + commentTextView.layoutMargins.bottom + commentTextView.font!.lineHeight
    let fixedWidth = self.view.frame.width - 32
    let maximumSize: CGFloat = 155
    let newSize = commentTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    print(newSize)
    if newSize.height > minimumSize && newSize.height <= maximumSize {
        commentTextViewHeightAnchor.constant = newSize.height
    } else {
        commentTextViewHeightAnchor.constant = newSize.height > minimumSize ? maximumSize : minimumSize
    }
    adjustScrollBehavior()
}
```

### Closing

I know this is a lot of code, but basically, that's everything I use. I have no idea why this happens, and I would be incredibly grateful for any help I could get.

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Can you share your xcode project, that will reduce the debugging time?

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t. It’s way too complex as it’s an entire app.

Comment: Can you check if this "flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 10)" is the problem. I am not sure just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I’ve tested it and can confirm that it’s not the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @linus_hologram - if you can't put together a [mcve] ... couple suggestions: It's not clear from the images you've shown which elements are which... give different background colors to your cell, supplementary and header views. Also, from your View Debugger screen-cap, it looks like you are getting duplicated cells (or cell contents), rather then unique items stacked on each other.

Comment: Hey @DonMag thanks for the feedback! I‘ll definitely have a look at it and try to clarify some of the things you mentioned. For now, please know that the View Debugger does not show duplicate entries - it’s 1 post (supplementary cell) and 4 comments (regular cells). However, the first three comments are stacked for some reason. The fourth one (the one that got submitted) is the only one that does not stack something. It’s just the cells of the comments that already existed before the comment was created. Upon reloading afterwards, everything then works again and looks good.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, any Idea @linus_hologram how were you able to solve this ?